# Import Error Attempted relative import when importing from another folder

Tags: python, python-import

It might be a pretty simple error but I don't get to solve it. The issue is that I have two folders, folder1 and utils. Inside folder one, I am trying to import a function from utils.py script in utils folder. Both folders have their respective **init** files. However, I get this import error and I don't know why.

Folder1

- Script1.py

utils

- utils.py

The way I try to import the package is:

```
from .utils.utils import *
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your code where you're trying to import?

Comment: I have edited the post so that you can see the way I'm importing it

Answer (score 0):

I had written a utility script which I wanted to use for rest of my scripts. This is how I import -

```
sys.path.append(path_to_script)

import my_util as mu

df = mu.get_data()
```

We need to add the path to `sys.path` and then we can access that as a module.

`path_to_script` is the absolute path of the directory where your script/files are.

---

If the script is in same directory then we can simply import it as -

```
import my_util as mu
df = mu.get_data()
```

In this case, we do not need to add the path to `sys.path` as well. It is simply like importing another file inside a python application.

Comment: is there any way to do this without explicitly add this path to the system? for example, using just a utils folder inside the package.

Comment: Okay. Curious to know. Does this method work for you?

Comment: Yes, it did, but I want to import the script from the other file. It should be easier in python to do this

Comment: If the file was in same directory, we could simply import it and use. No need of __init__.py also.

Comment: Does this work - `from utils import utils`?